# Console text editor

Tags: text-editor

Is there any vi/vim/pico/nano console build for android or any other editor which I can use in remote interactive `adb` shell. I don't need GUI at all.

I've seen Vi IMproved Touch and it's a nice example of editor which doesn't seems to have a console version which I need so much.

Answer (score 5):

`Vi` (or, its line-editor predecessors `ed` and `ex`) is always in-built with Unix and Unix-based systems.

If its not available in your device by default, install `busybox` (rooted device is required). Busybox bundles vi editor, too.

Answer (score 1):

Nano can be compiled manually, but also will needed Terminfo data for correct display text.
Another way is use vim: (precompiled here: http://mist.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/blog/?p=54 ).